Are these sewage vents or cleanout in our backyard?
We saw this in our backyard.  We are thinking the opening on the black pipe with the black cap tilted sideways is the sewer vent, and the grey "mushroom-looking" cap is to cover the sewer cleanout.  Or is it the other way around?  Other suggestions on what these could be would be greatly appreciated.  We are also thinking of digging around this area to help divert rain water away from side of house; any thoughts on if that will be ok?  Thank you in advance.

No idea what the mushroom (gnome hat) thing is. How about a pic with the hat removed. The black pipe look more like it would be part of a drainage system. Maybe where the downspout terminated in.  ( Downspout should be directed much farther away from the house.)

please add about water diversion in a separate question ... this site is not a chat forum ... both questions cannot be answered with one answer

Do you have a sprinkler system in the yard?
